# How to count both blanks and NAs in R

Tags: r, count, na, blank-line

I have a dataset `df` that has characters, blanks ("") and NAs. I would like to count the number of rows with non-data (blanks and NAs).

```
   ctd_id
1  D014241
2  D004026
3  C074702
4
5
6  D003633
7  C028617
8  NA
8  D014112
9  D001556
```

Is there a way to count both of these things?

I know I can count NAs with `is.na` - `sum(is.na(df$ctd_id))`, but this does not count the blank rows.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Try `nzchar`:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("a", "", NA))

sum( is.na(df$a) | nzchar(df$a))
## [1] 2
```

**2)** If strings containing only spaces are also to be counted then

```
sum( is.na(df$a) | nzchar(trimws(df$a)) )
```

**3)** Another possibility is `grepl`:

```
sum( is.na(df$a) | grepl("^ *$", df$a))
```